# Create a byte array with a specific size and from specific values

Tags: java, byte, arrays

I have a byte `array` with `10` `byte`s. I want to create an `array` of `byte`s with a specific size and it will contain only the specific `10` `bytes` randomly but frequency must be almost the same.

I got this:

```
public static byte[] a = {97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 49, 45};
```

I want to create a file with binary data that has *2000 `byte`s* size using the above `byte`s.

Comment: Please, give example what code do you have and examples byte array what you have and what you want to get.

Comment: @Viacheslav Vedenin edited

Comment: What do you mean by frequency?

Comment: @JayC667 how many times each byte appears

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way (from a code perspective) is to make use of [`Collections.shuffle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-), which shuffles Lists. To use that, you need to create a `List` of bytes with the distribution you want.

Here's some code that does that:

```
byte[] a = {97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 49, 45};
int SIZE_MULTIPLIER = 20;

List<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<>();
for (byte b : a) for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_MULTIPLIER; i++) bytes.add(b);
Collections.shuffle(bytes);
byte[] random = new byte[SIZE_MULTIPLIER * a.length];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.size(); i++) random[i] = bytes.get(i);
```

Note that is matters not how "random" the initial data is - in this case, it's convenient to load element 0 twenty times, then element 1 twenty times, etc.

Because the range of values is *not* random (each element is used the same number of times as every other element), the distribution of the final array will be identical to the distribution of the initial array.